# How to split the data based on row and rank in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have one sample data and I need to split the data based on rank and record basis, data looks like below format.

```
Rank    Rec_Type    Rec Load_Dt
--------------------------------------
1   PH  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX   2012-12-23
2   DE  YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY 2012-12-23
3   DE  YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY 2012-12-23
4   DE  YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY 2012-12-23
5   CD  YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY 2012-12-23
6   PT  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX   2012-12-23
7   PH  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX   2012-12-23
8   DE  YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY 2012-12-23
9   DE  YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY 2012-12-23
10  PT  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX   2012-12-23
```

`PH` is header and `PT` is trailer, While proting data from staging table to final table, I need to split the data based on header and detail basis as well as rank num.

The output should look like this:

```
Rank    RankNum Rec_Type    Rec Load_Dt
------------------------------------------
1   1   PH  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX   2012-12-23
1   2   DE  YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY 2012-12-23
1   3   DE  YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY 2012-12-23
1   4   DE  YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY 2012-12-23
1   5   CD  YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY 2012-12-23
1   6   PT  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX   2012-12-23
2   7   PH  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX   2012-12-23
2   8   DE  YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY 2012-12-23
2   9   DE  YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY 2012-12-23
2   10  PT  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX   2012-12-23
```

Once `PT` records touches the rank should change, can any one suggest on this?

Comment: Why the rank is not 3 for the 10th record? Or there will be 2 rank always?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this take same or less time to execute?

```
SELECT
  Rank = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable WHERE Rank<=A.Rank AND Rec_Type = 'PH')  ,
  A.Rank RankNum,
  A.Rec_Type,
  A.Rec,
  A.Load_Dt
FROM
  MyTable A
```

Comment: Yes, my bad, just copy-pasted top answer and forgot to remove it. Now corrected.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do it for you

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN B.Rank IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) + 1 Rank,
    A.Rank RankNum,
    A.Rec_Type,
    A.Rec,
    A.Load_Dt
FROM
    MyTable A
    LEFT JOIN MyTable B ON B.Rec_Type = 'PT' AND B.Rank < A.Rank
GROUP BY
    A.Rank,
    A.Rec_Type,
    A.Rec,
    A.Load_Dt
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3747f/1 for example